# Prioritizing indices in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr to search through indices written through lucene's index writer. My use case is pretty much close to log collection and analysis. I have the indices in 3 categories, hot, warm and cold.

Now that if I want 100 results from the indices, is there anyway I can ask solr to look into the warm category, only if hundred results are not available from hot, and also look into cold only if hundred results are not obtained still after reading hot and warm?

If the above is ambiguous, in simple terms, can I prioritize the indices in solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you query for 100 results and sort by the categories (hot -> 1, warm -> 2 and cold -> 3).
This way solr will arrange and return back the results accordingly in the order that is required by you.
You can add a facet to the categories so you get the count as well of how many results each of the categories had.

Comment: I don't have any field indiced as category. Since the ultimate challenge is to build this on top of already existing huge indices, is it possible?

And once again, reading all the indices is going to eat on my scaling, since the indices are HUGE

Comment: If you dont have any field indiced as category, how do you differentiate it ?

Comment: And the problem is today's hot is tomorrow's warm and day after tomorrow's cold. So I am afraid I cannot cling on to your answer. Any better suggestion/workaround?

Comment: I move it across cores. I have 3 cores. I learnt that having different cores is the easiest way to search across different indices.

Comment: So its per date right. So the logs that are latest should be on top ? you should be able to sort on date and club in from shards ?

Comment: Yeah that must be one way. I am worried about the scalability yet. But anyways if that is the only way, then I will have to make a compromise. Thank you Jayendra for your time.